# FIPS compliant SSH library for Java

Tags: java, ssh, scp, fips, nss

I want to implement SCP (Secure Copy) functionality in my Java application to copy a file from the SSH server to another machine. My java application must be FIPS compliant and hence it uses SunPKCS11 provider to interface with the underlying NSS key database.

To implement the SCP functionality, we can use any of the following SSH libraries for Java:

- JSch
- vngx-jsch
- Apache MINA SSHD
- Ganymed SSH-2
- sshj
- SSHTools

I have the following questions regarding these SSH libraries:

1. Are any of the above libraries FIPS certified?
2. If not FIPS certified, are the algorithms (cipher, key exchange, MAC
   etc...) used FIPS compliant?
3. Are there any other FIPS certified/compliant SSH libraries for Java?

The following links seem to suggest that JSch is NOT FIPS compliant:

- http://www.mail-archive.com/jsch-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00554.html
- http://planetjava.org/java-jsch/2012-05/msg00019.html

Comment: Almost any library would be FIPS-compliant, but you don't need this - you need FIPS-certified libraries. And this is completely different story. Do the search for "FIPS-certified".

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using JSCAPE's [Secure iNet Factory](http://www.jscape.com/products/components/java/secure-inet-factory/). Documentation can be located [here](http://files.jscape.com/secureinetfactory/docs/html/index.html?overview7_2.html).